# Server & Client Connection in Java

Tags: java, java-server

Here is an sample TCP/IP Server and Client programms

**TCPServer**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

    class TCPServer
    {
       public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
          {
             String clientSentence;
             String capitalizedSentence;
             ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);

             while(true)
             {
                Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
                BufferedReader inFromClient =
                   new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
                DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
                clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
                System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
                capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
                outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
             }
          }
    }
```

**TCPClient**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPClient
{
 public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
 {
  String sentence;
  String modifiedSentence;
  BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
  DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
  BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
  sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
  outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
  modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
  System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
  clientSocket.close();
 }
}
```

In that Client i need to send text hi to Server. Onces the server reads that text Hi from Client side it display Client Id with Text is Active now

Comment: what is your problem actually?

Comment: i need to get a list of computer connected through lan i got through by looping InetAddress now i need to check wheather that computer is ready for i have to create server and client

Comment: Can you elaborate more the question?

Comment: i need to send message form local host to remote i know ip address for the remote connection

Comment: @Bucks you have now stated three separate requirements. If you want to loop through InetAddresses there is no evidence of it in your code. Not a real question.

Comment: @EJP i completed that parse but i need to send a message form one pc to another pc. i am sure the above code is works in local host but i need to send a message form local host to another computer connected to server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [socket.getInetAddress()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInetAddress%28%29) to get an [InetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) object including the IP address then call the [InetAddress.getHostAddress()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostAddress%28%29) to get it as a string.